# Security exception with ASP.NET AJAX toolkit

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I've got an ASP.NET WebForms app that I've written, which uses the ASP.NET AJAX Toolkit.  I've put the MultiView control onto the web form, and it worked fine, when I had it under Vista.  Well, I had to replace my machine (HD failed) and I went to Windows 7 Ultimate.  I tried copying the ASP.NET app from the system (before it finally failed for good) and put it onto the Windows 7 machine.  I can bring up the app fine, go to all pages, but the one with these controls on it.  When I do I get the following error:

> Security Exception
>
> Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the
> security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your
> system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.
>
> Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of
> type 'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

What's going on?  How do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix this in my dev environment (local machine) by changing an advanced setting on my Default Application Pool.  The section titled 'Process Model' has a setting 'Load User Profile'.  When I changed this to 'True' the issue stopped happening.

Comment: WOW, interesting!  I'll have to check that out, thank you Kevin G.  Since that change is to the Default Application Pool I suppose it will affect all ASP.NET apps, correct?

Comment: Thank you!  I had been migrating my AJAX app to a new web server and started seeing this error.  After a couple hours of trying different things, your solution was the quick fix that resolved it.